# Rails RESTful website vs user experience and less clicks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, view

Situation: I have a team model, a user model and a teamate model for the users of a team.

Say I want to have a view that contains the information of a team team/show
and that I wish (to simplify the user's experience) to add a list of the users, an add user to team and the possibility to remove a user from that team.

To be perfectly restful, I would need a controller (let's call it Teamates), it would handle the users of a team.
I would have all the CRUD needed.

Is it clean to have the team/show view call the teamates controller for the following actions: adduser, removeuser, listusers.

What I am trying to achieve is less clicks for the users. 
In other words, I would like the user to be able to manage the users of a team from the team view instead if requireing him to navigate even further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a controller for teamates.

**And you really should not have adduser/removeuser/etc actions in your team controller!**

You could set up your routes like that:

```
resources :teams do
    scope :module => "team_scope" do
        resources :users
    end
end
```

Then you would have a UsersController in `app/controllers/team_scope/users_controller.rb`

To create a new user for a team, you would post to: `/team/1-team-a/users` and it would hit the `create` action in the UsersController above.

When you use `scope` in your routes, it does not change the route helpers like with `namespace`. The `new` action would just be accessible via `new_team_user_path(@team)`.

---

Hum... so yeah, in this case I would have a TeamatesController, and maybe set up my routes like that:

```
resources :teams do
    resources :teamates, :only => [] do
        collection do
            get :edit
            put :update
        end
    end
end
```

And then you could edit the associations between a team and its players...

Your form would post the users id to `team_teamates_path(team)`...

But I'm really not sure it's the best way, I'd have to think about it. This is not really restful as well.

Comment: The relation between users and teams is a many to many one, so basically one user can have multiple teams too. The problem with this is that I do not want to create a user, I want to assign one to a team.

Comment: Yeah ok.. I edited my answer, judge by yourself if it's acceptable. Not sure it's the best option.